# Find all positive integers n such that $n + 3$ divides $n^2 + 27$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find all positive integers n such that $n + 3$ divides $n^2 + 27$.

I am quite stuck on how to conclusively show all of the solutions. I tried look at the intersections of $y = n^2 + 27$ and $f = x(n + 3)$ where is $x$ is some number. But it still involves setting $x$ values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $x^2+27=(x-3)(x+3)+36$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\frac{n^2+27}{n+3}=n-3+\frac{36}{n+3}$$
hence $n+3$ divides $n^2+27$, iff $n+3$ divides $36$, that is
$$n+3\in\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18, 36\}.$$